# WebRTC iOS Safari - 2+ remote streams, only 1 plays back

Tags: ios, safari, webrtc, kurento

Has anyone else been able to get multi-party video conferencing working on iOS Safari?

We attempted to do a test of our conference client yesterday and on Safari only one remote stream and the local loop-back had the video and/or audio playing back.

My instincts are telling me this might have something to do with video management for battery life on iOS mobile devices, and before I start going that direction I thought I'd see if anyone else has encountered this issue and resolved it?

The first thing I tried was shrinking down the capture size on the client side to 320 x 240 but that didn't seem to affect it.

Android Chrome handled 3 participants just fine so I don't think it's a problem with the client/server ice negotiation and streaming.

A side note, we are using Kurento media server and running all streams through there. This is not exclusively peer-to-peer.

Comment: did you get any ideas about this or found any solution?

Comment: @VladPintea We haven't tried supporting safari in awhile. I'd recommend on not supporting it still until the next major version of ios.

Answer (score 0):

We got it working for most iOS versions, with what I call the iOS-hack informally. Basically when you attach the video you set from js "playsinline" rather than in HTML, for some reason that works for iOS Safari.

Some versions of iOS still won't work, but it opens up a lot of major versions. I have found out that iOS 11 on iPad still doesn't work, for example.

```
vid.setAttribute('playsinline', 'true');
```

[a simple example with 3 static videos](https://codepen.io/vlad-pintea-g-rtner/pen/poJNgRz)